# visualize irregular data in vtk

Tags: vtk

I have an irregular data, x dimension - 384, y dimension - 256 and z dimension 64. Now these coordinates are stored in 3 separate binary files and i have a data file having a data value for these points. I want to know, how can i represent such data to be easily visualized in vtk.

Till now we were using AVS which has fld files, which can read such data easily. I dont know how to do it in vtk. Would appreciate any pointers in this direction.

Answer (score 2):

My best answer would be write a small program that reads in the files and then fills a vtkImageData object and then save it using vtkMetaImageWriter or something?

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData> ImageData = vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>::New(); 
ImageData->SetDimensions(384,254,64); 
ImageData->SetOrigin(0.0,0.0,0.0); 
ImageData->SetSpacing(1.0,1.0,1.0); 
ImageData->SetScalarTypeToDouble();
ImageData->AllocateScalars();   
for(int i=0; i<z_dim-1; i++){
   for(int j=0;j<y_dim-1;j++){                             
     for(int k=0;k<x_dim-1;j++){
          double pix= pixel from data file
          double* pixel = static_cast<double*>(ImageData->GetScalarPointer(k,j,i)); 
          pixel[0] = pix; 
          } 
     }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write a short program to convert the files to a VTK native format. They are straightforward to work with, and there are ASCII and binary flavors. They are described in this document: www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf

You may find this helpful also: http://www.rug.nl/cit/hpcv/visualisation/VTK/avs2vtk/man.html - if you dig through the page, there are scripts there to convert AVS files to VTK formats, it may be a good start point.

Hope this helps,
Carlos-

Answer (score 0):

You can use [paraview](http://www.paraview.org/) to open all files, merge the points and visualize.
[here is a example for load files](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/Loading_Data)

you can save the vtk file too like this example
[here is a example for save the points](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Users_Guide/Saving_Data)